# Is SO getting too [corporate]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, scope

Converting the question in a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) as suggested in the comments.

I believe the tag [corporate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corporate) should be burninated.

It fails all the preliminary checks before burnination:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

**No**,

Questions having this tag as the one and only tag are unrelated to writing code and using tools to do that. Questions having this tag with other tags refer to company policies, software deployment across the company, etc.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

**No**,

It's not directly related to writing code and using tools to do that.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

**No**,

The tag excerpt and wiki are empty. As people who write code and use tools to do that, "corporate" doesn't provide any meaningful information.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

**No**,

It is also problematic because:

1. it might lead people to think that is OK to ask questions about "corporate" when it's not.
2. it makes people lose time when search engines point them to Stack Overflow.

---

Should [corporate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corporate) be removed or should we keep it? If we should keep it, what should be the next steps (add a tag excerpt / wiki, do a tag clean-up...)?

---

Searching [Shadow IT on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Shadow%20IT%22), the first result that I got was [The pros and cons of "Shadow IT" in software development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/874242/1595451) from 2009. This question has only one tag: [corporate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corporate). This tag

- has no tag excerpt / wiki
- has 61 questions
- has the following related question (shown in corresponding widget on the side panel)

  - [When does innovative software development shows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2829341/1595451)

    ```
    - this question is tagged [tag:corporate][tag:innovation].    
    - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421550/1595451
    ```
- has the following related tags (shown in corresponding widget on the side panel):

  - proxy × 17
  - android × 4
  - version-control × 4
  - docker × 4
  - node.js × 3
  - git × 3
  - php × 3
  - iphone × 3
  - firewall × 3
  - content-management-system × 3

---

Other "corporate" tags

- [corporate-policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corporate-policy), no tag excerpt, 15 questions.
- [opencorporates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencorporates), no tag excerpt, 4 questions. (There is a REST API called `opencorporates`, so this one might be on-topic.)

Comment: IMHO it should be burninated.

Comment: @Rubén perfect, thanks! Added a customary punny title too :) Feel free to change to the one you like more.

Comment: Yes lets burn corporations. ... oh you mean the tag? Okay.

Comment: 60 posts. This is so close to the 50 post limit of using the small burnination procedure... What if 10 posts would mysteriously get retagged or closed somehow? I'm definitely not suggesting anything here... coughcough.

Comment: @Lundin that'll likely result in a couple mod messsges to the involved at a minimum :) If you recall, there was a blunder a couple months ago regarding exactly that (not messages, I mean - the tags disappearing)...

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Regardless, there's so many bad questions under this tag that it justifies going through them and closing where necessary.

Comment: @Lundin absolutely - just noting that for other readers to not get any ideas :) Last time it was a major blunder, unfortunately.

Answer (score 12):

I agree, we should remove this tag from the site. There is nothing about "corporate" code that is different from non-corporate code... A corporation is a legal business entity/distinction, not a programming concept, paradigm, or category. It isn't even related to the licensing of code; many corporations have open-source projects or code bases that are freely editable under licenses like MIT.

Comment: Looks like the tag is no longer on any questions. :)