# Is [innovation] a good tag for SO?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

Since the tag has less than 50 questions and commenters aggreed that the tag should be burninated, I proceeded to remove it. Only the locked posts still have [innovation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/innovation).

---

This is a "spin-off" of [Is SO getting too [corporate]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421548/1595451)

Should [innovation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/innovation) be removed or should we keep it? If we should keep it, what should be the next steps (add a tag excerpt / wiki, do a tag clean-up...)?

---

Searching [Shadow IT on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Shadow%20IT%22) the first result that I got was [The pros and cons of "Shadow IT" in software development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/874242/1595451) from 2009. This question has a related question (shown in corresponding widget on the side panel)

- [When does innovative software development shows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2829341/1595451)

  - this question is tagged [corporate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corporate)[innovation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/innovation)

Regarding [innovation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/innovation)

- tag excerpt and wiki:

  - > May refer to the Innovation HTTPClient Java library.
- has 22 questions
- has the following related tags (shown in corresponding widget on the side panel):

  - programming-languages × 3
  - java × 3
  - user-interface × 2
  - operating-system × 2
  - matlab × 2
  - kubernetes × 1
  - backwards-compatibility × 1
  - end-of-life × 1
  - relational × 1
  - history × 1

Questions having [innovation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/innovation) as the one an only tag:

- [Significant new inventions in computing since 1980](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432922/1595451) (locked) from 2009
- [What is your company's stance regarding (technological) 'innovation'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/666090/1595451) from 2009
- [How do you promote innovation in your organization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/672848/1595451) from 2009

All of them looks to be off-topic.

Some other questions that looks to be off-topic

- [Remembering a quote from Alan Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357813/1595451) (locked) from 2009
- [A company that had a successful product but went bust for not innovating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2884535/1595451) from 2010
- [Which innovations (like MVC, xunit, Hotspot) did Smalltalk bring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7875007/1595451) from 2011

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be disambiguated.

Comment: @Dharman Assuming that the tag excerpt is good enough for now... what about renaming it in order to prevent be confused with "the practical implementation of ideas" (taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innovation)

Comment: What name do you propose?

Comment: @Dharman Disambiguated how?  There appears to be exactly [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13654173) about the HTTP client.  There's absolutely zero coherent theme to the on-topic questions.

Comment: @Dharman Nevermind the link in the tag wiki is broken. I think that it's fair to assume that library is not longer available. The questions having [tag:innovation] as the only tag look to be refererring to the "practical implementation of ideas" and be off-topic.

Comment: @RyanM You are right. I thought there would be more. The library is dead and there's only one question. The tag can be removed then